# Whats the best way to store/handle file attachments in WPF with a local database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, file, attachment

heres the quick background of the app

Basically..

1. Multiple users(usually only one) per machine
2. local sql server database running on each machine holdings its own data
3. WPF app has ability to export data in the table to zip files

As it sits now, I cannot change the environment its on.

I see two options with dealing with saving/uploading attachments to docs(pdf,doc)
currently there are no sizing requirements or required extensions to my knowledge

1. Saving each file as a varbinary directly into the database and using FK's and a reference table to get those file attachments back in the application for opening
2. Having the same FK's and reference tables, but I save to file to some folder on the local harddrive(hash + encryption?).  Then I rename that file to a generic name and store the name and location of that file in the database.

the first option seems hokey when I dealt with this in web development, but since I had an application server I didn't have to worry about possible user interference.

I like option two, but the files can be moved by the user and throw everything out of whack, and possibly leaves the option for orphaned child records in the database or orphaned files.

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a supporting version of SQL Server your best bet is to use the [FILESTREAM data type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) as it provides a lot of performance benefits to make it worth while unless all the stored objects will be less than 1MB.

**From the article:**

> If the following conditions are true, you should consider using
>   FILESTREAM:
>
> Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB.
>
> Fast read access is important.
>
> You are developing applications that use a middle tier for application
>   logic.
>
> For smaller objects, storing varbinary(max) BLOBs in the database
>   often provides better streaming performance.

Hope that helps!

Comment: looked at it, and it looks exactly what I want.  having sql server handle the pointer references and eliminating the possibility of exceeding varbinary max is solved.  Along with saving it on the file system instead of the database file.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your requirements.

If you want to be able to copy the SQL database from one machine to another, or if you want to have full disaster recovery by restoring a database backup, then option 1 is your best selection. Of course this means that your DB can grow quite big.

If you want to keep your database small and you can make sure your directory or file system is protected, and you do not need the requirements mentioned above, then option 2 is a good choice.

I don't know your requirements, but for my projects in the past option 1 has always been the best.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of performance VS consistency. I have a 1 GB collection of images (~100 KB each) served from a binary column in a local SQL Server database and things work smoothly. We even allow installing the DB as a distant server for multiple users and still works fine (we don't support a lot of concurrent users though).

We used to have an Access DB with files on disk, but the user often messed the file structure up and files went missing, etc. Storing them in the DB has proved very reliable and not so bad for performance. Backups, permission management and import/export are very easy.

I'd recommend option 1 unless you have performance requirements that dictate otherwise.